# Angular Universal html lang tag

Tags: angular, universal, lang

In Angular Universal I have an index.html file. At the top it has

```
<html lang="en">
```

I would like to change this based on the page I am on. maldonadoattorney.com/es/jailreleases would be

```
<html lang="es">
```

maldonadoattorney.com/jailreleases would be

```
<html lang="en">
```

Is there an accepted way of doing this? Have read other questions and DOCUMENT is deprecated, so am wary of using it.

I have my site map set up with hreflang tags, but would like the html lang tag to be correct. Currently, I'm taking the lang="en" tag out of my index.html.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You're right but `DOCUMENT` from `@angular/platform-browser` is deprecated in favor of `DOCUMENT` from `@angular/common`.

So you can use the following code:

```ts
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

...

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.document.documentElement.lang = 'es'; 
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: If you are using angular-i18n and want to change locale based on build, also do `@Inject(LOCALE_ID) locale: string` in the constructor to get the language code and set `locale` to `this.document.documentElement.lang`.

Answer (score 1):

Update for 2023, Angular 15, the code works, but I had to add a few imports, like this:

```
import { Component, Inject, InjectionToken, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
...
export class HomeEsComponent implements OnInit {

constructor( @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.document.documentElement.lang = 'es'; 
}
}
```

Hope it helps somebody else who's looking for the same.

Comment: And why does it need these imports? What do they do?

Comment: @SwissCodeMen The code needs these imports to bring up all the decorators and methods needed from the different angular libraries, to manipulate the HTML attribute. Otherwise, if you execute the code without these imports, it'll show you an error saying that it couldn't find the resources or the word you typed in the code "doesn'texist". You can comment the imports and try to run the code, so you can see what I mean. Happy coding! :D