# Update index.html lang attribute dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript

This is pretty much an update of [AngularJS dynamic lang attribute of html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461711/angularjs-dynamic-lang-attribute-of-html) for Angular >= 2.

My application is localized in three languages which the user can change dynamically, without page refresh. I need to set the index.html language attribute accordingly.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My application</title>
    <base href="/">
</head>
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

I need help only on changing the tag attribute, the application is already localized and supports language change.

Comment: This may answer to your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53990773/angular-universal-html-lang-tag

Comment: Seems event better but will it match only the root index.html file or any lang attribute in the application? I'm pretty sure i have only one of those but it would still be good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelector('html')?.setAttribute('lang', 'de');` to access the root `html` element and change the language attribute on it.

Comment: You should rather inject 'DOCUMENT' and use it to update it